# Py2exe can't seem to find my file in library.zip

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, exe, py2exe

I am trying to create an exe file from my program written in Python 2.7 (using GTK+ layouts). I have consulted this guide: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK and tried to set up my files accordingly. I succesfully make an .exe file, but when trying to run it, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipherka.py", line 183, in <module>
  File "cipherka.py", line 18, in __init__
GError: Nelze otevřít soubor "C:\Repa\cipherka\dist\library.zip\gui.xml": No such file or directory
```

While I cannot find the gui.xml file in the library.zip archive, it is available on the same level as the main .exe (cipherka.exe) file. If i copy it into the .zip file on my own, it doesn't solve the problem.

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import glob

setup(
    name="cipherka",
    windows = [
                  {
                      'script': 'cipherka.py',
                  }
              ],

    options = {
                  'py2exe': {
                      'packages':'encodings',
                      'includes': 'cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject, gio',
                  }
              },
    data_files=['gui.xml',
                'README',
                ("modules", glob.glob("modules/*.*")),
                ("media", glob.glob("media/*.png"))
    ]
)
```

Any help will be wildly appreciated! And I can give you any necessary info when needed. Thx

### UPDATE:

Allright, I implemented the change. However, it does weird things. When i use:

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\library.zip','')
```

it works when ran from the .py file, but fails when compiled with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipherka.py", line 217, in <module>
  File "cipherka.py", line 18, in __init__
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

When i use

```
path = os.path.dirname('gui.xml').replace('\\library.zip','')
```

instead - the program stops running from python and the compiled version gives me the following:

```
C:\Repa\cipherka\dist\cipherka.exe:188: GtkWarning: gtk_tree_path_append_index: assertion `index >= 0' failed
C:\Repa\cipherka\dist\cipherka.exe:188: GtkWarning: gtk_tree_model_get_iter: assertion `path->depth > 0' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cipherka.py", line 217, in <module>
  File "cipherka.py", line 55, in __init__
  File "cipherka.py", line 188, in changed_cb
IndexError: could not find tree path
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"gui.xml"` is in `"C:\Repa\cipherka\dist\"`, not `"C:\Repa\cipherka\dist\library.zip"` as your code supposes.

This should work whether your program is compiled or not.

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\library.zip','')
xml_file = open(os.path.join(path, 'gui.xml'))
```

Comment: I am not sure I enirely understand. How come the program normally runs when ran in python? Will it run in python if not compiled with this change?

Comment: Updated! Waiting for new ideas.

Answer (score -1):

the error reported is due to scripts running under `py2exe` do not have a `__file__` global. Detect this and use `sys.argv[0]` instead in your `.py` file.

Comment: i.e. replace where os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) with os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])) .